# Unit component vector notation

Tags: notation, vectors

If I have a vector $\vec v = \langle1,2,3\rangle$, then I can denote the magnitude with $\| \vec v \| = \| \langle 1,2,3 \rangle \|$, but I don't think I can just show the unit vector with $\hat v = \widehat{\langle1,2,3\rangle}$. How would I show that I plan to take the direction of a vector which is in component form later in the work?

ie, is there an in-line way of writing $\frac{\langle1,2,3\rangle}{\|\langle1,2,3\rangle\|}$?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I don't think I can just do  $\hat{v} = \widehat{\langle 1,2,3 \rangle}$"?, could you clarify what's the difference of $\vec{v}$ and $\hat{v}$?

Comment: $\hat v$ is the unit vector; $\vec v$ is the vector it's in the direction of.

Comment: Are you asking whether the "hat" notation applies to vector expressions that aren't just letters?

Comment: @Karl I'm asking whether there is something you can put on the component form of the vector to show that you're going to make it into a unit vector so that you don't take up so much space like how you can with magnitude

Answer (score 0):

According to [wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalizedVector.html), you can indeed use the notation $\hat{v}$ to denote $\frac{\overrightarrow{v}}{\|\overrightarrow{v}\|}$

So if

$$\overrightarrow{v} = \langle 1,2,3 \rangle$$

then

$$\hat{v} = \widehat{\langle 1,2,3 \rangle} = \frac{\langle 1,2,3 \rangle}{\|\langle 1,2,3 \rangle\|}$$